# How to write a recursive function(dynamic foreach loop on parent child combination in MVC.net)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

i have a parent id and child id...this child id is also the parent of some child..i.e. parent having multiple child..and these multiple child having parent of some child..
example:Suppose A is the parent of B,C,D and E...if B has some child name G,H,I and G has some child having J,K..now how to use foreach loop here in this case???
now how to use foreach loop???
Here is the code but it works for only single parent child relationship(suppose A having B,C,D child):

```html
 @model Abacus_CMS.Models.AbacusModel  
@{  
Layout = null;  
//for parent  
var ParentCatagoryList = Model.AbacusMenuList.Where(x => x.ParentCatagoryId == 0).ToList();  
//for parentchild  
var ParentChildMenuList = Model.AbacusChildMenuList.Where(x => x.ChildParentId != 0).ToList();  
}  
@*//add sidebar parent and their childname*@  
@if (ParentCatagoryList.Count > 0)  
{  
<ul class="page-sidebar-menu " data-auto-scroll="true" data-slide-speed="200">  
<li class="sidebar-toggler-wrapper">  
<!-- BEGIN SIDEBAR TOGGLER BUTTON -->  
<div class="sidebar-toggler">  
</div>  
<!-- END SIDEBAR TOGGLER BUTTON -->  
</li>  
@foreach (var item in ParentCatagoryList)  
{  
<li>  
<a href="@Url.RouteUrl("GettingStarted", new {catname =HttpUtility.UrlEncode(item.Name.Replace(' ', '-')) })" id="@item.Name.Replace(' ', '-').ToLower()">  
<i class="icon-user"></i>  
<span class="title" style="margin-left: -24px;">@item.Name</span>  
@*<span class="arrow " style="height: 4px;"></span>*@  
<span class="icon-01"style="float: left;  
margin-top: -2px;  
margin-left: 20px;">  
<i class="fa fa-angle-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>  
</span>  
</a>  
<ul class="sub-menu">  
@foreach (var childitem in ParentChildMenuList)  
{  
if (item.Id == childitem.ChildParentId)  
{  
<li style="margin-left: 38px;">  
<span style="background: #999999; width: 4px; height: 4px; float: left; margin-left: -20px; margin-top: 13px;"></span>  
<a href="@Url.RouteUrl("GettingStarted", new { catname = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(childitem.ChildName.Replace(' ', '-'))})" id="@childitem.ChildName.Replace(' ', '-').ToLower()">@childitem.ChildName</a>  
</li>  
}  
}  
</ul>  
</li>  
}  
</ul>  
}
```

here one loop i get parent and another loop i get child...
soo for multiple combination what should i do??
How to write a recursive function(dynamic foreach loop on parent child combination in MVC.net)??

Comment: you need to use recursion - so a function which you can call repeatedly to produce the same pattern. On the first pass you input the top-level parent, then you call the same function again for each of its children, passing in the children as input. It will then call each of their children in turn, and so on, until it reaches the bottom of the tree.

Comment: how can you describe me???can you post a answer??

Comment: I could, but maybe you should try it first now that I've given you the concept, and then edit your question if you still get stuck. There are plenty of articles online explaining recursion in more detail if you need to develop your understanding. It's a really useful concept to learn, and the best way to learn is by doing :-). I will happily help you later on if you make an attempt and then encounter a specific problem.